# Unable to connect to RethinkDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I am connecting RethinkDB using NodeJS and when I write following code, it produce some error:

**Connection Code:**
var r = require('rethinkdbdash')();

**Error:**

```
Creating a pool connected to localhost:28015
FATAL ERROR: node::PBKDF2() Out of Memory
1: node::Abort()      
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, 
v8::Local<v8::Message>)  
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
3: node::ClearFatalExceptionHandlers(node::Environment*)  
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
4: node::crypto::RandomBytesWork(uv_work_s*) 
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
5: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)
(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))  
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal:: 
(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>
(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous     
namespace)::BuiltinArguments<(v8::internal::BuiltinExtraArguments)1>)   
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
7: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, 
v8::internal::Isolate*) 
[/Users/RedlizardStudioz/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node]
8: 0x8bccdc092a7
9: 0x8bccde9721d
```

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8571).

Comment: yes.. the issue was because  I was using latest version v6.6.0 of NodeJS . I have now downgraded NodeJS version to 4.0.0 and it's working fine now.